# PDO Connection Timed out Between EC2 and Aurora

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, amazon-ec2

I have a multi server set up at Amazon, an Aurora DB cluster, a staging EC2 instance (1), a development EC2 instance (3), and I just launched a production EC2 instance (2).

All of the EC2 instances were created in Laravel Forge and are deployed via Envoyer.

All 3 EC2 instances use the same host and login credentials for the DB cluster, just different databases.

Server 1 and server 3 connect to the DB just fine, but the new production server 2 throws the following error:

```
[PDOException]                               
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

Server 1 and server 2 are exactly the same Laravel application, just different branches, and have different `.env` files, but the DB credentials are exactly the same.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I would get a timed out error when the credentials are the same?

I've double checked the security settings for Aurora and it's set to receive all public traffic (for the time being) so it's not that.

How can I trace this in Laravel or another tool to troubleshoot this?

Also I can connect remotely to the DB from my Macs through SequelPro with no issues as well.

Both branches of the code are up to date as well. It's simply the production server that won't connect.

Comment: can you connect to Aurora using mysql client from the new production server?

Comment: I never use mysql from the terminal, can you give me an example of how to do it and I'll give it a try. Thanks for the response btw.

Comment: This link will help you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connect.html

Comment: Ok I followed the directions listed there but I get the following: `WARNING: --ssl-verify-server-cert is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY instead.
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL certificate validation failure`

Comment: And what happens if you use the new option?

Comment: `ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL certificate validation failure`

Comment: Can you connect to other servers?